# Python error exception handling with less return statements?

Tags: python

I have a function with a try catch block where I have:

```
def testfunction():
    try:
     good = myfunction()
     return good
    except ExceptionOne:
         error="Error ExceptionOne".
         return error
    except ExceptionTwo:
         error="Error ExceptionTwo".
         return error
    except ExceptionThree:
         error="Error ExceptionThree".
         return error
```

Is there a way such that I could structure this in such a way where have a single return statement for all the exceptions?

Comment: `.. except (ExceptionOne, ExceptionTwo, ..) as e:`. Any maybe use `e` meaningfully. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Are you sure you should be returning something in the error case, rather than letting the exception propagate or throwing a new exception? Sometimes that's what you want, but it's a common newbie error to catch exceptions you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
def testfunction():
    try:
        good = myfunction()  # or `return myfunction()` if the case is actually this simple
    except (ExceptionOne, ExceptionTwo, ExceptionThree) as err:
        error = 'Error %s' % err.__class__.__name__
        return error
    return good
```

Of course, I'm not exactly sure what the purpose of this is.  Why not just let the exception propogate and handle it higher up?  As it is, you need logic to check the return value to see if it's good or not anyway, I think it would be cleaner if that logic was bound up in exception handling rather than in type checking or string value checking ...

Comment: @Nabla -- It turns out that I initially forgot the `return error` statement and then it was [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20964428/revisions) to change `return good` into `return error` by another user :)

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I thought it was already returning `good` above, and I ended up changing the error to a different error. (Though now I think it'd be cleaner to move the `return good` to the point where the value is created, so it's just `return myfunction()`.)

Comment: @user2357112 -- I'm not sure what is more clean in this case.  As a rule of thumb, I always minimize the amount of code in the try block to avoid catching exceptions I don't know how to handle (or worse, catching exceptions I do know how to handle at the wrong point).  Of course, in this case, the `return` statement *can't* raise an exception, but in other cases it might (e.g. `return good()`) so I pulled it out.